# Ansible warning on jinja2 braces on when

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am using this code in vars

```
MY_VAR: "{{lookup('env','MY_VAR') | default(true, true)}}"
```

i am using it like

```
- include: task.yml
  when: MY_VAR
```

This worked without any issue in Ansible 2.2

in Ansible 2.3 I get warning like this

```
[WARNING]: when statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters
 such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: {{lookup('env','MY_VAR') | default(true,
 true)}}
```

So if I use this  `MY_VAR: "lookup('env','MY_VAR') | default(true, true)"`, I mean remove `{{ }}`, then I get no warning but `MY_VAR` is always evaluated as true no matter if i pass false as ENV variable. which works fine in previous code i gave

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest way would be probably to set a fact instead of using a template in a variable (it will also prevent the lookup plugin from being called multiple times in included tasks - not a huge performance gain, but somewhat cleaner):

```
- set_fact:
    MY_VAR: "{{lookup('env','MY_VAR') | default(true, true)}}"
```

Also mind that it will evaluate to `true` in all cases when the environment `MY_VAR` is different from `false`.

---

> if I [ ] remove `{{ }}` then I get no warning but then `MY_VAR` is always evaluated as true

Because it will be considered a string and non-empty string value evaluates to `true` (with the exception of a string value equal to `false`).

Comment: Thanks,  will MY_VAR be available in all other playbooks as well. i mean suppose i have 3 playbooks and in 1st playbook i set fact for MY_VAR. Then in 3rd playbook , will that be available or i need to use hostvars